# Java Method Chaining Optionally based on arguments

Tags: java, option-type, method-chaining, notnull

If a 3rd party requests an argument `attachments` in a method, how may I avoid using an `if` and break method chaining, knowing that my argument may be null? The method has the following definition.

```
// import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
EmailBuilder withAttachments(@NotNull List<Attachment> attachments);
```

I would prefer **NOT** using an if condition for .withAttachments, when attachments == null. I know that javascript has method?(), but what is appropriate for java8, or above? In the case where (attachments == null), I don't want to call `.withAttachments()` at all. But, I don't see syntax comparable to methodA?() like in javascript, or typescript.

```
return emailBuilder()
  .withSubject(email.getSubject())
  .withReplyTo(replyAddresses)
  .withAttachments(attachments) // This is conditional...based on attachments
  .withHeader("X-showheader", email.getShowHeader());
  .build();
```

Would I be required to do this?

```
EmailBuilder eb = emailBuilder()
  .withSubject(email.getSubject())
  .withReplyTo(replyAddresses);
  if(attachments)
    eb = eb.withAttachments(attachments); // This is conditional...based on attachments
  eb = eb.withHeader("X-showheader", email.getHeader())
  .build;
return eb;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you can't change the contract of `withAttachments` to ignore calls with null?  You could, upstream wrap attachments in an `Optional` and then provide an `orElse` with an empty, but not null, impl of whatever type `attachments` is, e.g. (assuming `attachments` is a `List`):

```
Optional<...> optionalAttachments = Optional.ofNullable(attachments);

...

.withAttachments(optionalAttachments.orElse(Collections.emptyList())
```

**UPDATE** (based on input from comment, hat tip to Andreas)

You could also achieve this with a ternary, e.g.:

```
.withAttachments(attachments != null ? attachments : Collections.emptyList())
```

Comment: Rather than using `Optional`, use a ternary operator: `.withAttachments(attachments != null ? attachments : Collections.emptyList())`, though you might have to hint it using `Collections.<Attachment>emptyList()`

Comment: Thank you, @Andreas

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the ternary operator. The original question was missing the fact that the method included a @NotNull annotation, but this still worked.

Answer (score 4):

If `withAttachments()` doesn't allow a `null` value, then yes, you need `if (attachments != null)`.

But, since builders don't (generally) require a specific order of method calls, you can clean the code up a bit.

```
EmailBuilder eb = emailBuilder()
        .withSubject(email.getSubject())
        .withReplyTo(replyAddresses)
        .withHeader("X-showheader", email.getHeader());
if (attachments != null)
    eb.withAttachments(attachments);
return eb.build();
```

Comment: You're right. Forgot to format my comment. I posted a new comment.

Comment: When using kotlin, you could also use `attachments?.let{ eb.withAttachments(this) }`

Comment: These are both good answers.  I chose the answer below, because I am using Java only in this project, and though I appreciate the note that moving the method to the bottom, the answer below does remove the IF, as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach you can use if you can edit or extend the builder.

```
public class ChainBuilder {

  public ChainBuilder ifApplicable(
    Supplier<Boolean> filter,
    Consumer<ChainBuilder> extension) {
    if (filter.get()) {
      extension.accept(this);
    }
    return this;
  }

  public ChainBuilder withAttribute1(String attribute1) {
    //handle store attribute1;
    return this;
  }

  public ChainBuilder withAttribute2(String attribute2) {
    //handle store attribute2;
    return this;
  }
  
  public SomeData build() {
    return new SomeDate(); //with the optional attributes
  }
}
```

The client code can chain the methods:

```
SomeData data = new ChainBuilder()
      .withAttribute1("A")
      .ifApplicable(() -> false, builder -> builder.withAttribute2("B"))
      .build();
```

It is just an illustration. If you have several conditions, it might make sense to inlcude this into the builder class.